# options for mobile app store analytics (Apple, Android, OVI, etc)?

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, app-store, nokia

Does anyone have any experience with analytics software/services for the mobile app stores? I am currently developing only for iOS so that's what I'm mainly interested in, however I would like to know if there are some analytics that aggregate data across several app stores in case I make some say Android apps.

I find the iTunes Connect reporting a bit lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been pretty happy with [appFigures](http://www.appfigures.com). It's only for iPhone apps but it's good enough that I decided to pay for it month to month. They also offer a free trial so you can give it a try before paying or staying on the free plan (which I was on for a while before deciding to go premium). [App Annie](http://www.appannie.com) is another option for iPhone apps.

I'd be interested to see if there are services that aggregate across different revenue sources -- for example, I have AdMob ads in one of my apps and I'd like to see appFigures grab that data too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Check the answer that i put is free and can analyze all the markets.

Answer (score 1):

I am using appanie and I have to recommend it to you, it's very informative.
I currently also use Admob but I think I am going to test ad networks aggregator services like adwhirl and inmobi and run admob as a portion of my served ads, while trying others.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for sales and download analytics then by all means go with appFigures or App Annie.

But if you actually want proper customisable usage analytics, then look no further than [Google Analytics for Mobile](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/)

Check out [the slides from a talk](http://analdroid-talk.heroku.com/) I gave a few days ago on using Google Analytics in my own app, to work out how to optimise user experience.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question and i found the perfect solution for all the markets

http://monitor.distimo.com/

Android market, iOs appStore, ovi, GetJar, Amazon, windows 7 ....

Its perfect!