# Analytics for Android Market/AppStore app sites to view visits, pageviews, sources etc

Tags: app-store, analytics, google-play

How can I view analytics information - like visits, pageviews, traffic sources etc. - on my Android Market or AppStore app site? It would be quiiite interesting to see how users came to the site and how much the conversion rate is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[INSTALL_REFERRER](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#campaigns)

This is already implemented in Admob Android paid campaigns (no house ads, see Tools -> Conversion Tracking).

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643265/is-there-a-quick-way-to-check-current-iphone-app-store-rankings

And here: [Scripts to parse and download iTunes Connect and AppStore data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937899/scripts-to-parse-and-download-itunes-connect-and-appstore-data)

And here: [options for mobile app store analytics (Apple, Android, OVI, etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555619/options-for-mobile-app-store-analytics-apple-android-ovi-etc)

Pageviews/traffic sources info, however, is not available. For one thing, both stores exist primarily as mobile apps, not as Web pages - the very notion of Web stats does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is active user tracking and custom event tracking in mobile app. There are some options. The one I tried and works well for me is **Google Mobile Analytics**: http://www.google.com/analytics/features/mobile.html

Other options are:

- **Bango mobile** - http://bango.com/mobileappanalytics/
- **Flurry** - http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html
- **AppClix** (unique solution - you can deploy to your own servers) - http://www.appclix.com

Hope that helps!

Comment: No I don't need active user tracking (i.e. within the app). I need conversion tracking (i.e. outside the app). "Which traffic source converted in which market and how much?"